# Несколько вопросов по Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Уже давно пишу под андроид в эклипсе. Но изредка приходится подделывать в Visual Studio (2012). Кое что раздражает, но не могу вспомнить, где это менять надо. Один момент только, стоит ещё решарпер7.

Как убрать этот серый прямоугольник на текущей строке кода: http://goo.gl/MCDDwt

И ещё: что это разные вертикальные линии слева от кода, желтые, зеленые?

UPD1: а как называется команда или какой у неё шорткат: под отладкой - выполнение до указанной строки (в эклипсе это Run To Line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу "прямоугольника". Убрать его можно, сняв следующую галку:

> Tools => Options => Text Editor => General = Highlight current line

Зелёные и жёлтые линии показывают области в файле с кодом, которые вы редактировали. Жёлтые - не сохранённые изменения, зелёные - сохранённые

> а как называется команда или какой у неё шорткат: под отладкой - выполнение до указанной строки

Run to Cursor Ctrl+F10